# Given a command whose STDOUT prints to several lines, how might I format each of them (e.g. prepend a string, change a color, etc.)

Tags: bash, shell, stdout, formatting, color

Okay, so, contrived example here, but it's the simplest instance I could come up with the produces the conditions I'm trying to alter.

I'm trying to run a black-boxed command and alter the multi-line output. So say `git diff --name-only`, which outputs each uncommitted file that has been altered in the current branch, one per line:

```
/my/path/altered-file.ex1
/my/path/altered-file.ex2
/my/path/altered-file.ex3
```

Now, assuming I'm NOT trying to run any tests on them (e.g. there will be no "only style *this* line's filename if...") and that I simply wish to modify - cosmetically - the way ALL of them are being outputted to the screen:

```
   -=> /my/path/altered-file.ex1 <=-
   -=> /my/path/altered-file.ex2 <=-
   -=> /my/path/altered-file.ex3 <=-
```

and/or possibly color them, yellow, let's call it (again: contrived example here), operating with that same assumption that each line will get the same cosmetic treatment  as all the others (that is to say, ALL will be yellow and/or ALL will get the same formatting pre/appended).

I'm CERTAIN there's some mechanism to pipe the command into something (`xargs`? `awk`? `tput`? hell, some `echo` syntax I'm simply too hungover to dredge up?) that'll vomit them, formatted, right back out again (I KNOW this is a boneheaded question, but I've been tearing my hair out for a good half hour here; for the life of me I cannot seem to press-gang my brain into getting anything to WORK, lol).

Anyone got any good suggestions?

Comment: MOD: I'm not sure if it was more appropriate to stuff this here or in the *NIX Exchange. I'm working on the server, so that was where my brain went. I'll relocate it if this is the wrong namespace.